# Global generation of twists of formal vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, formal-schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety (over $\mathbb C$) and $Y\subset X$ a complete intersection of ample divisors $H_1\cap H_2\cap \cdots\cap H_r$.
In the proof of Grothendieck-Lefschetz, a crucial point is that twists of locally free sheaves on the formal completion $\widehat{X}$ of $X$ along $Y$ are globally generated as proven in Proposition 1.3, chapter IV of [Hartshorne](https://eudml.org/doc/203415).
There are 4 parts to the proof of the above proposition. The only reason why the assumption $dim(Y)\geq 2$ is needed seems to be able to prove that $H^1(\mathcal F_k(m))$, where $\mathcal F$ is a locally free sheaf on $\widehat X$ and $\mathcal F_k=\mathcal F/(\mathcal I_{H_1}+\cdots+\mathcal I_{H_k})\mathcal F$, is finite dimensional.
But where is this fact needed in the rest of the proof?